# Liferay Tomcat https stops working after couple of days. when restart server https starts working

Tags: tomcat, ssl, memory, https, liferay

I have a Liferay Server with SSL Installed. When i start server i can access it through https but after couple of days(normally 4-5 days) https stops working and i have to restart server.

I did some R&D on that and found that Rect-Q is getting full.
[image]

for this Situation i increased memory:
**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.core.optmem_max=134217728
net.core.rmem_max=134217728
net.core.wmem_max=134217728
net.core.rmem_default=67108864
net.core.wmem_default=67108864
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=87380 87380 134217728
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=87380 87380 134217728
net.ipv4.tcp_mem=134217728 134217728 134217728
net.ipv4.udp_mem=134217728 134217728 134217728
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min=87380
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min=87380
```

But Still Doesn't Help.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are several reasons why a Tomcat would stop responding : all threads busy, database connection loss, singleton object becoming unavailable,.. Start by checking the logs to see Exceptions (particularly database related), check connections established to the database, and if still nothing generate a thread-dump.

Comment: Yes just like Eugene mentioned,try to dig in any additional connections to DB outside of service builder which might be left unclosed

Comment: Thanks, but Issue is http is working only https stops working, so in case of memory leak server should stop responding but here only https stops responding